# "node-gyp configure" fails with ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7-x64, node-gyp

`npm install -g node-gyp` was successful but `node-gyp configure` throws the error below. Trying to upgrade node version in our application.

Mine is a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

```
D:\App>node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@6.9.2 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2-headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
gyp ERR! stack at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\IMVNode new version\IMV
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Try running it again?

Comment: Yeah i did. Tried to apply a couple of solutions from similar questions asked before. Nothing helped. Same issue exists for my teammates as well.

Comment: Are you able to download `https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2-headers.tar.gz` using a browser? What does `curl -v http://nodejs.org/` show?

Comment: D:\IMVNode new version\IMV>curl -v http://nodejs.org/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x25c6070
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x25c6070) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to nodejs.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 104.20.23.46...
* Connected to nodejs.org (104.20.23.46) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: nodejs.org
> Accept: */*                 ******Continued****

Comment: **Cntd*
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 07:08:46 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Location: https://nodejs.org/
< CF-Cache-Status: EXPIRED
< Expires: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 07:08:46 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
* Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 31c519d362e43816-ATL
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d3ac69a8a9af0127ab9da9baddd61e7bd1483600125; expires=Fri, 05-Jan-18 07:08:45 GMT; path=/; domain=.nodejs.org; HttpOnly
< Connection: Keep-Alive
*Cntd*

Comment: *cntd*

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host nodejs.org left intact

Comment: Sorry i had to post the result of curl -v nodejs.org in 3 comments. Not able to post it in a single comment.

Comment: Was able to download node-v6.9.2-headers.tar.gz

Comment: Weird. Do you have a firewall set to disallow outbound connections by default? Does installing packages from npm work?

Comment: Firewall not quite sure. npm install gives the following error:

npm ERR! memwatch-next@0.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the memwatch-next@0.3.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the memwatch-next package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild